# Fixed div inside scrolling static div

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I have an element `container`, which *must* remain static. Inside it lies `fix`, which I need to be fixed when `container` overflows and I scroll in it.

Example:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 850px; height: 200px; position: static;">
    <div id="fix"></div>
    <div id="otherStuff" style="width: 2000px;"></div>
</div>
```

Can I do this with CSS?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? It's very confusing what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the content you want to overflow in an element with `overflow-x: scroll`, and the `#fix` element will stay where it is.

```css
.overflow {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="width: 850px; height: 200px; position: static;">
  <div id="fix">fix</div>
  <div class="overflow">
    <div id="otherStuff" style="width: 2000px;">otherstuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```